# blank page is loading when I run my php application. No error message is displayed

Tags: php

> I made a web app for login using OOP concept without connecting to the database. I have included separate functions for each activities but due to my lack of knowledge about oops and php made some logical mistakes. when i run my app in xampp i'm not getting any output simply blank screen is loading  help me out to fix it, i'm sharing my code below
>
> No error messages are displayed .

## function.php

```
<?php session_start();

     class loginAction {

        var $username;
        var $password;


         function checkLogin($username,$password) {

            if($username == 'admin' && password == '123'){

                $_SESSION['auth']['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['auth']['password'] = $password;

                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }

        }

         function logout() {

            session_start();

            session_destroy(); /* Destroy started session */
            header("location:index.php");
            exit;
        }
    }

?>
```

## index.php

```
<?php

include_once "function.php";

     $loginAction = new loginAction();

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

        $loginAction->username ='admin';
        $loginAction->password = '123';


        header("location:home.php");
                exit;

    } else {

                return "<span style = 'color:red'>Invalid Login Credentials</span>";
            }

            return 0;


?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form">
  <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="Table">
    <?php if(isset($msg)){?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><h3>Login</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top">Username</td>
      <td><input name="username" type="text" class="Input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Password</td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" class="Input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="Button3"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## logout.php

```
<?php
include_once "function.php";
$loginAction = new loginAction();
$loginAction->logout();
?>
```

## home.php

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])){

    if($_SESSION['auth']['Username']=='admin' && $_SESSION['auth']['Password']=='123'){


    }else{

    header("location:login.php");
        exit;
    }   
}   
?>

Congratulation! You have logged in<br><a href="logout.php">Click here</a> to Logout.
```

Comment: 1. make `error_reporting` ON 2.  remove `session_start()` from function.php & add it in `index.php`

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu : still the same result :(

Comment: in your index.php write ini_set('display_errors',1); & error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu : where i have to include this code?? on top of the page or what??

Comment: typo : missing dolor  near  this line  password == '123'

Comment: @JYoThI : thanks .but still the result is same ..page is still blank

Comment: try answer it will work @DeepakVijay

Comment: @JYoThI : i tried your code but it is not working . not redirecting to home page ..

Comment: i tested in my localhost it's working perfect @DeepakVijay  i think you need to re look to my code . remove that unwanted returns . typo dolor missing . etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145685/discussion-between-deepak-vijay-and-jyothi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  you need to call the method with post value like this

2) check the return Boolean value and redirect to home otherwise show error message .

3) And remove that unwanted return .

**index.php**

```
    include_once "function.php";

     $loginAction = new loginAction();

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

        $loginAction->username ='admin';
        $loginAction->password = '123';

        $result = $loginAction->checkLogin($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);

        if($result){

            header("location:home.php");
             exit;

            }else {

                echo  "<span style = 'color:red'>Invalid Login Credentials</span>";
            }


    } 


?>
```

**Home.php**

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])){

    if($_SESSION['auth']['Username']!='admin' && $_SESSION['auth']['Password']!='123'){
         header("location:login.php");
        exit;

    }
}   
?>

 Congratulation! You have logged in<br><a href="logout.php">Click here</a> to Logout.
```

Comment: i made the changes in index.php as u said now the application is loading fine without any error . but while trying to login its is not working ..the form is not getting submitted ..

Comment: :Thankyou for your help

Comment: glad to help you @DeepakVijay

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your `index.php`, you will see that it never gets past the first php code block: In that block you either `exit;` or `return` a value (`0` or a string).

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script
>   file is ended.

So you need to remove the `return` statements from `index.php`.

Also notice that you should only show an error if an actual post request was made; note having `$_POST['Submit']` set is not necessarily an error.

Comment: i made a change like this is this worthy?? header("location:index.php");
             exit;
            } else {

              return "<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
            }
          
          return 0;

Comment: it worked when i removed those else part from index.php the login page is loading now. but the appliacation is not working if i click the submit button its  redirecting to the home ..not checking the conditions